# Liquibase with Database interaction

Tags: java, spring-mvc, liquibase

I'm researching about Liquibase to intergrate Database with Spring. I want to ask: is there any plug-in or something like that use to auto-save the change in database by liquibase. :D
for ex: I insert new row into user table (userid, username, password), then that plugin auto-generate db-changelog.xml:

```
 <insert ...>
   <column name = "userid">...</column>
   <column name = "username">...</column>
   <column name = "password">...</column>
</insert>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry all. I read document about [generate changelog](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/generating_changelogs.html) from liquibase official page and find out solution. Thank you for reading my question. :D

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that there is such plugin. I think you can export necessary tables into CSV files and use [Change: ‘loadData’](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/load_data.html) You can use database tools for export and integrate them into build process.

Answer (score 1):

Liquibase is designed mainly for schema changes - changes to the structure of your database tables, indexes, procedures, etc. It has some ability to work with the data in the tables, but if you want to automatically replicate data from one database to another, there are better tools for this purpose. Perhaps you could describe the problem you are facing.

Comment: Maybe my last describe is not good.
For ex: I have my local database, when I change mine, I write out liquibase changelog.xml file manually and another one can update their local database.
I wonder if is there any tools help mr to write out changelog.xml file automatically.
Thanks for helping!